# Python Pandas Remove Duplicate Cells - Keep the rows

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicates values of specific columns based on a single column, while keeping the rest of the row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4],'B':[5,5,6,7],'C':['a','a','b',c'], D:['c','d','e','f']})
```

I want to delete the values in column A & B based off the duplicates in column C, but keeping all of column D.

Expected output:

```
A B C D
1 5 a c
      d
3 6 b e
4 7 c f
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using simple `loc`

```
df.loc[df.C.duplicated(), ['A', 'B']] = ''

    A   B   C   D
0   1   5   a   c
1           a   d
2   3   6   b   e
3   4   7   c   f
```

Can also use `np.nan` instead of empty string not to mess with the dtypes

Comment: yep, `np.nan` is a better option here.