# Python Pandas Remove Duplicate Cells issue

Tags: python, pandas

I am fetching data from a big DB, and I am trying to represent. I want to use pandas to trim it however, as the SQL DB query uses several joins and the returned table actually has a lot of duplicate cells. I found the following question:

[Python Pandas Remove Duplicate Cells - Keep the rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52338468/python-pandas-remove-duplicate-cells-keep-the-rows)

This does the job for me, however with some bugs. I think I might be using it wrong. Can someone explain to me a bit how it works?

I my case (see the spinet) I use a column called `Product` as the main axis of the loc (if this is correct to be said like that). Afterwards I am trying to filter the duplicate cells in ALL the other columns from the dataframe and replace with empty string:

```
df.loc[df.Product.duplicated(), ['Type', 'ID', 'Device', 'MID',
                                'Technical Description', 'Zx', 'Package', 'Connector',
                                'Wavelength', 'Chip', 'Code', 'FType',
                                'Orientation']] = ' '
```

This removes cells from the `Device` column which actually are not duplicates. I really can't get it. I apologize if this is stupid!

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Here is the code for the dataframe and DB connections:

```
with connect(database='measurements') as connSQL:    # Use a context handler for the connection
    pdQuery = pd.read_sql_query(''' SQL CODE ''', connSQL)

df = pd.DataFrame(pdQuery, columns=['Product', 'Type', 'ID', 'Device', 'MID',
                                    'Technical Description', 'Zx', 'Package', 'Connector',
                                    'Wavelength', 'Chip', 'Code', 'FType',
                                    'Orientation'])
```

Output for only 1 product selected:

- **Without cell filtering:**
  [image]
- **With cell filtering:** The code described above.
  [image]

Is there a way to selectively remove cells? Should I apply this to several columns in order to leave only the unique values per column?

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: `This removes cells from the Device column which actually are not duplicates.` - yes, it is expected, because you set values by `Product`  duplicates.

Comment: @jezrael Is there a way to fix it (go around)?

Comment: I am waiting for data sample... Some problem with it?

Comment: Do you need check each clumn separately? Like `df = df.mask(df.apply(lambda x: x.duplicated()), '')` ?

Comment: If I check each columns separately, will this show only the unique values in the table? For example in the table above, the ID appears actually one 2 times, but it has associated with it several Devices.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Hard to know, not idea what is expected output

Comment: using the lambda function worked! Thanks a lot of the help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need replace duplicated values to empty strings for each column separately use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) per each column by [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df = df.mask(df.apply(lambda x: x.duplicated()), '')
```

Comment: Hey @jezrael, a quick question... can I use the np.nan instead of the empty string in the mask function?

Comment: @pr07ecH70r - sure, then is possible omit `''`, because default value for mask is `NaN`